# The view blog.views.post_list didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-views

I cant fix this Help!!!!!

The view blog.views.post_list didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from .models import Post


def post_list(request):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'page': page, 'posts': posts})



def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                               publish__year=year,
                               publish__month=month,
                               publish__day=day)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post})
```

Comment: Check if there is any other method named `post_list()` in your code.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Are you sure that function always hits a return?

Comment: I get a similar error, but I have a **Class Based View**